# Unable to properly create the password protected zip file using Rebex library

Tags: c#, rebex

I am trying to create a password protected zip file using the Rebex libraries.

Here is the code that I use

```
using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(ZipFilePath, ArchiveOpenMode.Create))
{
   // Set the Password first
   zip.Password = strUserPIN;

   // Change the default Encryption algorithm
   zip.EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256;

   // Add the file to newly created "files" folder within the zip file
   zip.AddFile(Temp_BPI_SaveLocation + strDataFilewithTimeStamp, @"\files\");

   //Save the Zip file
   zip.Save();

   // cloase the zip file
   zip.Close();
}
```

However, when I try to open the file I don't get the expected 'Password needed' dialog.

Instead I get the error message saying 'Windows cannot complete the extraction. The destination file could not be created'

I do need to get the expected 'Password needed' dialog so that I could properly extract the file

Has anyone ever dealt with that issue and found a solution?

Comment: Is the produced ZIP file actually intact and not corrupted? Use extraction utilities like 7-zip (or others like WinRAR, WinZip, etc...) to inspect the ZIP file (what are the directory and file name(s) inside) and see what results/error messages you get if you try to extract it with those tools.

Comment: The produced zip file is obviously NOT intact. How do I make it intact using the Rebex?

Comment: (Side note: I am a bit puzzled by the leading backslash in your ZIP directory name `@"\files\"`. Directory entries in ZIP files usually do not start with a leading backslash. I know that Rebex ZIP tutorial also shows leading backslash, but that looks rather fishy to me...)

Comment: You start by investigating _how_ precisely the ZIP file is not intact. From there you should be able to find an approach to avoid the ZIP file becoming corrupted. Alternatively, you could also switch to a different ZIP library...

Comment: With regard to the leading backslash (or slash): See ZIP file format specification, section `4.4.17 file name: (Variable)` (https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). Quote: "_The name of the file, with optional relative path.
       The path stored MUST NOT contain a [...] or a leading slash._" Hence why i pointed out the leading backslash there as rather fishy. Since i don't know how Rebex processes the leading backslash given in the directory name string there, i can't tell for sure whether it is related to the problem or not...

Comment: elgonzo thank you very much for your reply. I did try to completely get rid of a second parameter (not used /files/ at all). Still didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I accepted from the Rebex forum

"It showed that the problem is in Windows extractor itself. You are using EncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256 to encrypt the ZIP archive, which is good choice, but this encryption algorithm is not supported by Windows extractor (please check [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-extract-zip-file-encrypted-aes-128/0920fcb9-1a87-4254-ab7d-ce8d85a8d8a6) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180515-00/?p=98755)).

The only encryption algorithm Windows extractor supports is legacy EncryptionAlgorithm.Zip20 algorithm, which is not secure in present (you can check it [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-secure-is-a-windows-password-protected-zip-file)).

The suggested solution is to use EncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256 algorithm to protect the ZIP archive and use a third party application to extract it."

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

The client used Windows OS built-in ZIP extractor to extract the produced ZIP archive. Unfortunately, Windows OS extractor is not capable of `AES` encryption, which caused the mentioned error. More details and possible solutions can be found at [Rebex forum](https://forum.rebex.net/9578/unable-properly-create-password-protected-using-rebex-library).

---

The error 'Windows cannot complete the extraction. The destination file could not be created' indicates that the file name contains some invalid characters for current platform. In your sample code you used `strDataFilewithTimeStamp` as file name argument, which probably contains colon ':', which is invalid character for file name on Windows.

It depends on the extractor what will be displayed in this case (password dialog or error).

To solve the issue, please ensure that the file name doesn't contain any of the invalid characters on Windows (please check the `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` method on Windows platform).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did try to hardcode very simple names, without any special characters. Still ended up with the same issue

Comment: I did post a question at the site you recommended

http://forum.rebex.net/9578/unable-properly-create-password-protected-using-rebex-library